# How do I programatically pass data when shell prompts for multiple inputs?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a java cli that asks user to pass y or n. I have to do this about a thousand times and there is no yes to all support in the CLI. How do I automate passing y to this cli?

Example:

```
$ ./command-to-run
do you want to delete x? (y/N) y
do you want to delete x1? (y/N) y
do you want to delete x2? (y/N) y
.
.
do you want to delete x1000? (y/N) y
```

I tried

```
seq 1000 | xargs -Is echo 'y' | ./command-to-run
```

It didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use [`yes` command line application](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html):

```
yes | ./command-to-run
```

For more complex interactions there is [`expect` application in multiple languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It is amazingly good at generating a load when you want stress a CPU too :-) Put 4 copies on in the background and you will max most machines out!